# how to write error message to DB with EF when SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With EF, any data value in Entity instance can be saved back to database by calling SaveChanges which can be overridden to add custom action.

So I try to override SaveChanges in following way:

```
public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
       {          
           try
           {
               return base.SaveChanges(options);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               //error log here  
               //write the error message to database table errorlog             
               throw ex;
           }
       }
```

when SaveChange failed, I want to grab the exception and save the error message to a table in same database.  With about code, even save data to table errorlog, also should call SaveChanges. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a new context instance in your catch block and log the error.

```
   public override int SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options)
   {          
       try
       {
           return base.SaveChanges(options);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           var context = new MyContext();

           // your log class instance populated with relevant details
           var error = new Error { Message = ex.Message; };

           context.Errors.AddObject(error);
           context.SaveChanges();

           throw;
       }
   }
```

Comment: This is not working for me... Any updates on this?.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Eranga's advice use separate context type just for error logging (it will map only `Error` entity). This new context type will not have overriden `SaveChanges` - that will avoid infinite loop in case of error fired during error saving.